# React Native WebView file upload in Expo

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I am using Expo to build a react native app.

It is all-webview app that RN is just a wrapper to render pages on app.

Here, I want to use an image picker to let user pick an image when click a button inside of webview.

I have read [webview docs](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md) but its guide seems to be for RN Cli apps.

I'll appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The **WebView will be limited** in this your question preventing these requested behaviors.

Try using a solution like **TWA**.

I've used this lib a while ago, I don't know if it still works, if not, try to find something similar. Good luck in your studies!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-trusted-web-activity

Bonus, try to see about Expo Web, there is a video, in Portuguese, but I believe that with subtitles, you will interpret it well.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqJKAJ0TKms